# Why = operator doesn't work with ROWNUM other than for value 1?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have the following query:

```
select * from abc where rownum = 10
```

**Output**: No records to display

I sure have more than 25 records in the abc table and my objective is to display the nth record.

If I write the query as: -

```
select * from abc where rownum = 1
```

it works fine and gives me the first record. Not any other record other than first.

Any idea?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Because row numbers are assigned sequentially to the rows that are fetched *and* returned.

Here's how that statement of yours works. It grabs the first candidate row and temporarily gives it row number 1, which doesn't match your condition so it's thrown away.

Then you get the second candidate row and *it's* also given row number 1 (since the previous one was tossed away). It doesn't match either.

Then the third candidate row ... well, I'm sure you can see where this is going now. In short, you will never find a row that satisfies that condition.

Row numbers are only useful for `= 1`, `< something` or `<= something`.

This is all explained in the [Oracle docs for the `rownum` pseudo-column](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm).

You should also keep in mind that SQL is a relational algebra that returns unordered sets unless you specify an order. That means row number ten may be something now and something else in three minutes.

If you want a (kludgy, admittedly) way to get the `n`th row, you can use something like (for the fifth row):

```
select * from (
    select * from (
        select col1, col2, col3 from tbl order by col1 asc
    ) where rownum < 6 order by col1 desc
) where rownum = 1
```

The inner select will ensure you have a consistent order on the query before you start throwing away rows, and the middle select will throw away all but the first five rows from that, and also reverse the order.

The outer select will then only return the first row of the reversed set (which is the last row of the five-row set when it was in ascending order).

A better way is probably:

```
select * from (
    select rownum rn, col1, col2, col3 from tbl order by col1
) where rn = 5
```

This works by retrieving everything and assigning the rownum to a "real" column, then using that real column number to filter the results.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please suggest any alternative to meet my objective? That is, displaying the nth record if I know the value of n?

Comment: Thank you so much. The Oracle doc says this: UPDATE my_table
    SET column1 = ROWNUM;
Better I will have a real column in the table and then filter the result with that. :)

Comment: @SaharHassan, the only problem with that is you need to maintain it. In other words, you'll probably have to have triggers or an auto-increment column. But none of that helps with the fact that result sets are inherently _unsorted_ unless you explicitly order them.

Comment: @paxdiablo to you have an idea how I can translate your second solution in HQL ? It does not accepting selects inner to from clause and order by in an inner select. So I feel hopeless !

Comment: @miss_R, no idea, I've never used HQL. But do you know who has? Probably many people here on SO who can't respond because they're looking for questions rather than comments :-) That's my (barely) humurous way of stating you'll almost certainly get a better response if you actually ask a question.

Comment: select id from (select id  from TABLENAME order by id desc) where ROWNUM = 1  , This will give us first record of the tables which is last inserted

Comment: @ananthkva, only if the `id` field is an auto-incrementing one :-)